# Angular diverting user to login screen

Tags: angular, express

I am using Express to serve markdown files for my application.  The application requires authentication which is implemented with a cookie with a JWT in it.  The key code looks like this:

```js
app.get('*.md',
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (fileIsPublic(req.path) || tokenIsValid(req.cookies[config.cookieName])) next();
    else {
      // console.log('doing redirect!', req.path);
      // res.redirect('/login');
      console.log('sending unauthorized', req.path);
      res.status(401).send({ message: 'no token' });
    }
});
```

Simply put if the user doesn't have a valid token and is trying to access a non-public file, then the client browser gets an HTTP 401 error.   On the client side the code looks like this:

```js
    // ...
    } catch (err) {
      const he = err as HttpErrorResponse;
      console.log('document service got error', he);
      if (he.status === 401) this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

This works as long as the client browser is running the Angular app.  However if the browser is fetching the data URL (say a link from another site) then the user simply sees the object `{ message: 'no token' }`.   The Angular app never runs and so the logic above does not apply.

If I do a re-direct (as in the commented-out-code above) that solves that problem, but it breaks the case where the application *is* running because when an HTTP 302 response is received from the server the application never sees it.   Instead the HttpClient get Observable returns the response it would have gotten if it had requested the redirected URL to begin with.   The Angular application never sees the 302 response even though it will show in the developer window.

So my situation is that I have code that works if the client is running my app, or if the client is **not** running my app, but not both at the same time.

I feel like I am missing something obvious but does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution I am not totally happy with, but I haven't seen anything better.

The key is that you have to use the **redirect** method on the server.  If you don't then if the user enters the application via an asset-matching URL path there will never be a chance for the Angular application to load.

On the client side, as I mentioned the 302 response never gets seen.  But what does happen is the **HttpResponse** object does get the URL that the server indicated was the target of the re-direct, and you can branch off of that.   So the client has:

```js
      const resp = await this.http.get('assets/' + path,
                   { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' }).toPromise();
      // console.log('document service pulled response', resp);
      if (resp.url.endsWith('/login')) {
        console.log('redirecting to login');
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
```

Note that the redirect does not cause the **get** method to throw anything.  It just returns an **HttpResponse**.   I hope this turns out to be helpful to someone.